# How to transpose table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

The database is SQL Server, and I have this table:

```
NODE |   Param1   |   Param2   |   Param3   |   Param4   |   Param5   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
node1| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |
node2| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |
node3| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |
node4| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |
```

And I am trying to transpose it like this:

```
PARAM |    node1   |    node2   |    node3   |    node4   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
Param1| some value | some value | some value | some value |
Param2| some value | some value | some value | some value |
Param3| some value | some value | some value | some value |
Param4| some value | some value | some value | some value |
Param5| some value | some value | some value | some value |
```

I am trying to use `PIVOT` but can't make it the right way

If I use this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (SELECT
        NODE ,
        Param1 
    FROM
        My_Table 
    ) TEMP 
PIVOT 
( 
MAX(Param1) FOR NODE IN (node1, node2, node3, node4) 
) PIV
```

then it transposes only one row

Comment: Why go from a lousy format to another lousy format?  Unpivot the table into one with one row per `param` and `node`?

Comment: Ok, maybe the right way is to unpivot it first and then use pivot

Answer (score 3):

You should really try to fix your table structures. Anyway, here is one way to do this using conditional aggregation.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2135/0)

```
WITH CteUnpivot(node, val, param) AS(
    SELECT node, Param1, 'Param1' FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT node, Param2, 'Param2' FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT node, Param3, 'Param3' FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT node, Param4, 'Param4' FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT node, Param5, 'Param5' FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    param,
    node1 = MAX(CASE WHEN node = 'node1' THEN val END),
    node2 = MAX(CASE WHEN node = 'node2' THEN val END),
    node3 = MAX(CASE WHEN node = 'node3' THEN val END),
    node4 = MAX(CASE WHEN node = 'node4' THEN val END),
    node5 = MAX(CASE WHEN node = 'node5' THEN val END)
FROM CteUnpivot
GROUP BY param
```